# 'x' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm struggling with a curious situation.  I have a collection of pages that I mean to iterate through in Razor.  I need to do it twice, once within a script tag and once outside.  now, I understand that Razor is meant to generate HTML and not Javascript but this was working fine and now it's breaking and I can't figure out quite why.  here's the code that breaks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @foreach (string page in pages)
    {
        <text>
        function @page() {
            // something here
        }
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

this works fine:

```
<div class="intro">
    @foreach (string page in pages)
    {
        <div id="@page">
            <!-- whatever -->
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS0118: 'page' is a 'variable' but is used
>   like a 'method'

and it points to the use of `@page`.  in fact VS13 also red-squiggles the use of the variable *but only in the first case*!

what's going on here?

Comment: why don't you use `eval()` to generate functions dynamically ?

Comment: What is `function @page()` supposed to be doing? (`page` is a `string` not a javascipt function name)

Comment: @page will contain at any point a string that is a valid function, e.g. `CustomerPurchase` or `PurchaseOrder`.  the idea is that every div I create on the page will have a Javascript function to manage it

Comment: @MokshShah, I don't know how using eval() would help.  the problem is that I have a dot-net collection for which I want to create a bunch of scripts.  I can write the script but I can't seem to refer to my variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ha! I figured it out.  it needs a bloody space, or some kind of expression terminator:

```
<text>
function @page () {
```

(notice the space after @page, which indicates to Razor the expression has ended), or:

```
<text>
function @(page)() {
```

of course, the IDE still whines about expecting an identifier (the function name), but that's because it's not meant to generate Javascript

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@foreach (string page in pages)
{
    <text>
    function @(page)() {
        // something here
    }
    </text>
}
```

Comment: yes, that was it.  I figured it out just as you posted.  I guess I was being "tidy" and removed the space, much to my dismay (this cost me a good 1/2 of frustration)